# how to list out a certain type definition in elm

Tags: elm

```
type alias Employee =
    { role : Role, name : String }


type Role
    = Engineer
    | Manager
    | Sales
    | Accounting
    | Hr


generateSample =
    Role.all |> List.map createModelWithType
```

I need to accomplish `Role.all`, which even `Role` in this case is inaccessible. What's the best way to accomplish / alternative way to express this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no automatic way to list all constructors of a type. You could build a list like this:

```elm
allRoles : List Role
allRoles =
    [ Engineer
    , Manager
    , Sales
    , Accounting
    , Hr
    ]
```

In Elm, there is no concept of a simple enumeration similar to other languages. Type constructors could also have arguments, which may help in understanding why there is no built-in way to enumerate a list of constructors.

Answer (score 2):

There are many considerations when choosing a type. It depends on what behavior will be used with the data. Maybe as you are learning you could simply choose a data type that works and seems simple enough to work with. With experience you will see the advantages of choosing a type over the other.

To get more inspired in the way of thinking in choosing type for different problems you might want to take a look at this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpDsk374LDE
There are two topics mixed in the presentation and one of them is how choosing type for different behaviors.

Here is one way to do it:

```
type Alias Role = 
     { Engineer : Bool
     , Manager : Bool
     , Sales : Bool
     , Accounting : Bool
     , Hr : Bool
     }
```

Comment: This is a good answer but, I want to point out that using a record full of Bools to describe a conditional state is a bit of an antipattern in Elm. There are 32 possible Roles using this implementation. Even if some combinations makes sense, `engineeringManager = Role True True False False False`, many don't, `hrSalesAccountant = Role False False True True True`.  We also lose out on compiler assistance. Consider if we add another Role, such as `type Alias Role = { ... , nitpickyCommentor : Bool }`, our code will still compile even though we haven't implemented case handling for our new role.

Comment: @TylerNickerson was that what he was arguing for? That looked extremely unproductive and I don't understood this solution.

Comment: @user2167582 My interpretation of the answer is that sometimes when you run into issues like this, it can be useful to rethink the datatypes you are using. However, I wouldn't follow their example literally. A record of `Bool` type fields is rarely a better option than a sum type that can explicitly describe all of it's states.

Comment: @TylerNickerson i think roles is what was meant to be used for types, and since so far I haven't discover any other way of enumerating and defining special types(type, type alias) i think for now we either have to explicitly ask for them, which is something elm should be getting rid of. Possibly adding an enumeration on `type` definitions?